# Freezed & json_serializable handling parsing error

Tags: flutter, dart, parsing, freezed, json-serializable

I'm looking for a general solution for handling parsing errors of complex (nested + fields of Any type) objects using Freezed and json_serializable.
It should use the default value in case a field can't be parsed, and not compromise the whole object.

Let's take this class for example:

```
@freezed
class Interest with _$Interest {
  const factory Interest({
    @Default('') String id,
    required String slug,
    required String name,
    required String image,
    required bool isPublic,
  }) = _Interest;

  factory Interest.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$InterestFromJson(json);
}
```

For illustration purposes, the backend response that I'm parsing could either have the `id` as `String` (as I have defined it) or `int`.
In the latter case, I will get a parsing error (as my `id` is a `String` and I received an `int`).

As a consequence, the whole object can't be parsed, even though the rest of the data is fine.

Thanks! ✌️

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own implementation of `JsonConverter` and annotate the specific field with it. Then you can control how you handle the conversion yourself, check typing and set to default values as you please.

Check details here:

https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable#custom-types-and-custom-encoding

And here:

https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/JsonConverter-class.html

Comment: Looks promising!

The only issue is that I'm looking for something general...
With this approach, I think I would have to write code for each possible type + annotate every single field.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `checked` boolean property in **@JsonSerializable()** annotation. You should be aware that a `CheckedFromJsonException` will be thrown during deserialization if parsing fails.

https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/JsonSerializable/checked.html

The problem with this is that it does not tell you which property is responsible for the cast parse error.
You would get something like:

`type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast`

You may have to result in handling this manually, without the help of json_serializable.